# authorizeResource() with nested resource

Tags: laravel

Say I have a nested resource controller

```
Route::resource('photos.comments', CommentController::class)->shallow();
```

In `CommentPolicy` I need to access `$photo`. The last post [here](https://github.com/laravel/ideas/issues/1612) shows a very interesting solution:

```
public function __construct() { $this->authorizeResource('App\Models\Comment,photo', 'comment,photo'); }
```

In `CommentPolicy`:

`public function create(User $user, Photo $photo)`

1. This works great for the `create` method in the controller, but not for the `store` method: `App\Policies\CommentPolicy::create(): Argument #2 ($photo) must be of type App\Models\Photo, string given`. Why?
2. Where can I find documentation for passing these type of arguments to `authorizeResource()`? Why does it work anyway? It seems to be undocumented.